# triangles and parallal lines

Tags: geometry

[image: In the given fig. $XYZ$ is a triangle, $XO$ bisects $\angle YXZ$, $OY$ is perpendicular to $XE$ and $OM\parallel XZ$, to prove : $YM = MZ$. ( I tried but this question seems to be asymptotic or the given conditions are insufficient, please try this!!)]

In the given fig. $XYZ$ is a triangle, $XO$ bisects $\angle YXZ$, $OY$ is perpendicular to $XE$ and $OM\parallel XZ$, to prove : $YM = MZ$. ( I tried but this question seems to be asymptotic or the given conditions are insufficient, please try this!!

A more accurate figure:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Let the line $YO$ intersect the line $XZ$ at $N$. Since $XO$ bisects $\angle YXZ$ and $YO \perp XO$, $|YO| = |ON|$. Since the line $OM \parallel XZ$, we have
$$|YM| : |MZ| = |YO| : |ON| = 1 : 1 \quad\implies\quad |YM| = |MZ|$$

[image: A little triangle]

Answer (score 0):

$\triangle XOY$ is congruent to $\triangle XON$ ...... [ASA]

Then, $YO = ON$ ................ [corr. measurement]

Together with $OM // XZ$, ......... [given]

Therefore, $YM = MZ$ ........ [intercept theorem]